# Convert a String time to a localtime to compare

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am trying to figure out the math to verify shifts are getting correct breaks, when I query the api I get the following response:

```
    "StartDate": "4/25/2018",
    "EndTime": "8:30PM",
    "StartDayNumber": 1,
    "StartTime": "7:30PM",
    "SegmentTypeName": "BREAK",
    "EndDate": "4/25/2018",
    "EndDayNumber": 1
```

I have tried various attempts at using `LocalTime` so I can use the function `Duration`:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(employeeShift.getJSONObject(ii).get("StartTime").toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm a"));
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(employeeShift.getJSONObject(ii).get("EndTime").toString());
```

I have tried various way to convert EndTime and StartTime to a local time. However I am stumped I have tried a various number of formatters including the day, the hour but I have not found an example that included the am/pm, do I need to convert to 24 hour time first?

The error I've got:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1:00PM' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: Why is there a space in your formatter?

Comment: I have tried with and without the space, same response. Happened to post the last attempt that I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fix your `DateTimeFormatter`. "HH" is the hour-of-day (values from 0 to 23). To parse AM/PM hours, you need to use "hh" (clock hour of am/pm, values from 1 to 12 - [check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)). Also, there's no space between the minutes and the AM/PM part, and to parse one digit hours, you can use just one "h" (it'll accept one or 2 digits, which seems to match your inputs):

```
LocalTime.parse("7:30PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.US));
```

I also used a `java.util.Locale` because AM/PM strings are localized, and if I don't specify one, the JVM default will be used - although for most locales "AM" and "PM" are used, there are other languages that produces things like "a.m." or some other string.

Comment: I swear I tried a formatter like that but apparently not. Thank you!

Comment: @MenoHochschild I don't the reputation to yet, otherwise, I would because it was a solid, succinct, and good answer.